# Effects of Hydrogen Peroxide Concentration in the Briggs-Rauscher Reaction and Workarounds for Dilution

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I am an IB chemistry student attempting the Briggs-Rauscher reaction, which requires a diluted solution of hydrogen peroxide. The experiment guidelines suggest diluting 400 mL of 30% hydrogen peroxide to 1 L, resulting in a 12% concentration. However, the highest hydrogen peroxide concentration available in my lab is 6%. I would like to understand the effects of hydrogen peroxide concentration on the Briggs-Rauscher reaction and seek possible workarounds or adjustments to achieve the desired reaction conditions.

Question:

How does the concentration of hydrogen peroxide affect the Briggs-Rauscher reaction? Specifically, what are the implications of using a 6% hydrogen peroxide solution compared to the recommended 12% concentration?
Are there any known workarounds or adjustments that can be made to accommodate the lower concentration of hydrogen peroxide (6%) available in my lab? If so, what are they, and what modifications should I make to the experimental procedure?

Note: I have already searched the Chemistry Stack Exchange and other resources but have not found specific information regarding the effects of hydrogen peroxide concentration in the Briggs-Rauscher reaction or suitable workarounds for dilution.